# Selenium select a tag with data-normalized-text

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrap a [website](https://www.dnca-investments.com/documents) using selenium. I am having trouble selecting an `a` tag from the html:

[image]

So far, i have tried the following, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[@data-normalized-text="<span class="text">LU1694789451 (Part A)</span>"]')
```

I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //a[@data-normalized-text="<span class="text">LU1694789451 (Part A)</span>"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//a[@data-normalized-text="<span class="text">LU1694789451 (Part A)</span>"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=103.0.5060.114)
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: What *"doesn't seem to work"* means? Add exception. Also add HTML as simple text.

Comment: Try [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Comment: What is the url you are looking to scrape, is it public facing? Also, post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: we can't see real page so we can't say what can be the problem. Maybe it uses JavaScript to add elements and it needs `sleep()` or better [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits) to wait for elements.

Comment: Also, we cannot determine whether the text in that element changes, or it can be used as a locator: do you need to locate a specific element, or an array of elements? How does the parent/parents tags look like, can you construct an XPATH to hook up into those? That's why providing the url is important.

Comment: The url is : https://www.dnca-investments.com/documents

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return all `a` tags containing a span with class `text`, as from what I could see in page, all links with that particular `data-normalized-text` attribute have. The setup is for linux, however you can adapt the code to your own, just observe the imports and the code after defining the browser/driver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')


webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.dnca-investments.com/documents'

browser.get(url) 

elems = WebDriverWait(browser,10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='text']/parent::a")))
print('Total links:', len(elems))
for elem in elems:
    print(len(elems))
    print(elem.get_attribute('outerHTML'))
```

This will return:

```
Total links: 1205
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>LU1791428052 (Part H-I (CHF))</span>" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">LU1791428052 (Part H-I (CHF))</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>LU1694789535 (Part B)</span>" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">LU1694789535 (Part B)</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>LU1694789451 (Part A)</span>" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">LU1694789451 (Part A)</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
<a tabindex="0" class="" data-normalized-text="<span class=&quot;text&quot;>LU1694789378 (Part I)</span>" data-tokens="null"><span class="text">LU1694789378 (Part I)</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span></a>
[...]
```

Note you can drill down to further ancestors, and then return and grab the links you want, depending on the category etc. Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

`<a>` tags are generally **clickable**.

To identify the **clickable** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[data-normalized-text*='LU1694789451'] span")))
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@data-normalized-text, 'LU1694789451')]//span[contains(., 'LU1694789451')]")))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I am getting TimeoutException

Comment: You are facing _`TimeoutException`_ as the element couldn't be identified and it can due to either of the following [reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447).